# What is the difference in the meaning between "etwas werden" and "etwas geworden sein"?

Tags: difference

What is the difference in the meaning of these two sentences?

> Ich wurde Arzt.
>   Ich bin Arzt geworden.

Especially *wurden* means *became*.

Answer (score -1):

If I am not wrong, then in this context, there is no difference in meaning or grammar, only the syntax is different. "wurde" in this context is often only a short form of "bin ... geworden".

Also when using "wurden" as "became", "bin ... geworden" might signalize a more active than passive situation. This means, that one might think that the speaker might have become something because of an external action instead of his own doing. It's like saying "They made me president." instead of "I became president.". Still, this is only a very very slight difference one might *interpret* into this sentence. In my opinion, there is no real difference.